# WCF netNamedPipeBinding message level security, is this possible?

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc, netnamedpipebinding

i am new with WCF, still learning.

I want to use netNamedPipeBinding for IPC, and i need it to be as secure as possible.
I already did a practice service for wsHttpBinding, where i used certificates, so i got that part covered up (using message level security).

As I can see, named pipes can only use transport level security (at least only transport shows up in visual studio auto-complete).

Is it possible to have some kind of encryption of messages based on let's say a machine key or something? If yes, where can I find some documentation on it or examples, I've been searching the whole internet for 2 days :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no point in encrypting messages just over the WCF named pipe connection: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809524/502194.

If you want end-to-end message security involving more than just the WCF connection (e.g. if one of the processes persists the messages to disk; or is only an intermediary with no reason to know the message contents) then you can develop a mechanism to encrypt/decrypt them yourself using the functionality in System.Security.